# Translating the statement: X is very common

Tags: word-choice, translation

I'm working with a computer translation program and the output I got was this:

> ぞれは一般的です。

I'm trying to determine whether this is a correct translation for 'That is common.' Alc gives  誰でも知っている［やっている・使っている］一般的 when I look up common, which has me thinking that the sense of the sentence is wrong.

The source sentence is: 'This type of implementation of the <do> tag on mobile devices is very common'.

Comment: I think the intention in the source sentence is 'it happens frequently' or something like that.

Comment: Are you sure it's ぞれは, not それは?

Comment: Oops, no, that's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it means "That is typical." Or 'That's not uncommon."

As with most short Japanese sentences like that, to make a translation into English, it depends on what kind of context is surrounding it.

Comment: The source sentence is: 'This type of implementation of the <do> tag on mobile devices is very common'.

Comment: @Hanne It would be best if you gave any available context in your question so that answers can be specific.  (There are a lot of ways to say "is very common", but some are more formal than others, for example.)

Comment: Yes I guess you're right... I didn't want to complicate things, but it does need context.

Answer (score 0):

> それは一般的です

Is more like, "that is commonplace."

While it's not incorrect, I'd say something along the lines of

> このモバイル・デバイス上のタグ実装手法はごく普通のである。

ごく普通 = fairly common/normal

or

> このモバイル・デバイス上のタグ実装手法は非常に平凡のである。

非常に平凡 = extremely common/standard

Although extremely standard is a bit of an oxymoron.